# Run time Debugging

Tags: c++

We have recently downloaded, installed and compiled gcc-3.0.4 code. gcc compiler has built successfully and we where able to compile some same test cpp file. I would like to know how we can modify gcc source code so that we add additional run time debugging statements like the binary in execution compiled by my gcc should print below statement in a log file:

> filename.cpp::FunctionName#linenumber-statement

or any additional information that I can insert via this tailored compiler code.

Comment: GCC 3.0 is a very old version, and the 3.x series was pretty poor in many ways. Why aren't you useing something more up-to-date? Also, the compiler already inserts this sort of debug information if you use the -g flag.

Comment: @Neil, I agree, but "very old" is almost an understatement.  3.0.4 was released in February 2002 according to this http://gcc.gnu.org/news.html.  That's not just old, that's ancient.

Comment: @Glen I still use Win2K, so calling it ancient would be a bit hypocritical :-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`? They do that for you without modifying the compiler. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Standard_predefined_positioning_macros) for more information.

My general understand of the GCC architecture is, that it is divided into front-end (parser), middle (optimization in a special intermediate language), and a back-end (generating platform dependent output). So, for your purposes you would have to look into the back-end part.

Comment: I am trying to exercise how we can modify gcc code to our requirement. Inserting macros will be painful as we have todo across hundreds of file. How can we modify gcc source code so that gcc compiler injects some additional data into binary which can be harvested when is executed.

Comment: Added some more info after your comment. I do not know too much about this, but hopefully it gives you a starting-point.

Comment: Is there any book that describes how we can code gcc and avail functionality like gcov build within

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you there.

Comment: Any idea how does code coverage tools / testing tools implement their functionality. Please have a look at the BullsEye testing tool - Bullseye Testing Technology, debugging and profiling tool - valgrind etc probably could be a few in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that with an ancient compiler like GCC 3.0.

With a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9 (in end of 2014 or january 2015) you could customize the compiler, e.g. with a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension, which would add a new optimization pass working on [Gimple](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html). That pass would insert a Gimple statement (hopefully a call to some debugging print) before each Gimple call statement.

This is a non-trivial work (perhaps weeks of work). You need to understand all of Gimple